# How to retrieve the $locationProvider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my code:

```
angular.module('foo', []).controller(
  'Main',
  [
    '$scope', '$location',
    function($scope, $location) {
      var params = $location.search(); // always returns an empty object
    }
  ]
);
```

This code doesn't work because of [#7239](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7239) bug in AngularJS. However, as a workaround, they suggest to turn html5 mode ON for a `$locationProvider`. The question is - where do I get it? [This page](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) doesn't really explain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Providers are only available during the module configuration phase. Something like this:

```
myModule = angular.module('foo', []);
myModule.config(function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

[Docs for $locationProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider)

[Docs for Module Configuration](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#module-loading-dependencies)

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fcCjnsg3h5VWYW1fIorS?p=preview)

Comment: hm.. this leads to `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]`. I'm using Angular 1.3.11